# Try to mask a textfield in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, action

I trying to mask a textField with the following code, but it's not working.

```
var Blue_clip:blue_img = new blue_img()
addChild(Blue_clip)
var field:TextField=new TextField();
var format:TextFormat=new TextFormat();
format.size = 40;
format.font = "Arial";
field.defaultTextFormat = format;
field.text = "Hello World";
addChild(field);
Blue_clip.mask = field;
```

Please guide me.

Comment: is your font embedded?

Comment: field.embedFonts = true;

Comment: i used,but not working

Comment: by "not working" what do you mean? is the field not masked, or not displayed at all?

Comment: if it is not displayed try `field.blendMode = BlendMode.LAYER;` (http://rabidgadfly.com/2008/10/making-alpha-work-on-as3-dynamic-text-fields/)

Comment: @SumitGupta i think that is not enough of embedding the font

Comment: @Shvilam is correct here, I think. Just setting `embedFonts` to true does not actually embed a font. That is textfield specific and allows for other different things (such as Advanced anti-aliasing and transformations). You need to physically embed the font, either through CSS (if using Flex), the library (if using Flash CS), or the Embed tag. Be careful, though. Arial is a premium font. Embedding it would require you get a license to use it within your app

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1) - Use runtime AS mask**

```
_root.attachMovie("mask", "mask_instance", 3 ,{_x:10, _y:20});
_root.masked_content_mc.setMask(mask_instance);
```

where mask is AS exported movie clip in lybrary (simple shape 100x100px for example)

**Method 2) - Embed font.**
You have to embed the font using Text->Font Embedding and then set it to the text field:

```
var style_tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
style_tf.font = "ArialEmbed";
style_tf.size = 16;
_root.my_text.setTextFormat(style_tf);
```